# php mysql нормализация базы, как лучше?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Почитал, про нормализацию, про формы нормализации, и вот все равно не могу понять как лучше, ниже 2 примера, какой из них лучше, или может можно еще лучше?(так сказать, может я плохо что то понял!)
п.с. все к тому что бы уменьшить размер, базы, предполагается, что будет огромная.

пример будет на человеке: у человека есть рост, вес, имя, дата рождения, страна + город рождения.

пример 1:

```
//таблица Человек
id |    data      | imya_id |   ves |  rost | strana_id | gorod_id
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 22.11.1988   |    1    |   60  |  160  |     1     |    2
 2 | 22.11.1987   |    2    |   65  |  170  |     2     |    2
 3 | 22.11.1990   |    3    |  null |  null |     1     |    2
 4 | 22.11.1991   |    2    |  null |  null |     1     |   null

//таблица Имя (имена повторяются, что бы уменьшить размер базы, или это лишнее?)
id | имя
----------
1  | vasya
2  | petya
2  | stepa

//таблица Страна
id | страна
-----------
1  | vasya
2  | petya

//таблица Город
id | город
-----------
1  | vasya
2  | petya
```

Исходя из того, что данные могут быть не известны(а их будет много), и что бы не засорять базу NULL значениями(null как я понял занимает память при фиксированном значении)
вариант 2:

```
//таблица Человек
id |    data      | imya_id
---------------------------
 1 | 22.11.1988   |    1    
 2 | 22.11.1987   |    2    
 3 | 22.11.1988   |    1    
 4 | 22.11.1988   |    1    


//таблица Имя
id | имя
-----------
1  | vasya
2  | petya

//таблица Названия данных
id | attr_name
--------------
1  | ves
2  | rost
3  | strana_id
4  | gorod_id

//таблица Данные
id | chelovek_id | znachenie | attr_name_id
-------------------------------------------
1  |     1       |    60     |      1
1  |     1       |    160    |      2
1  |     1       |    1      |      4
1  |     2       |    75     |      1
1  |     2       |    170    |      2
```

То есть во 2 примере в таблице "Данные" избавляемся от NULL значений, но такая таблица получится в конечном итоге очень большая, так как количество строк 4 раза больше, это пример, по сути будет еще больше чем в 4 раза и количество строк будет достигать 100+ миллионов(из расчетов в будущее).

Какой вариант лучше, или вообще никакой из этих, просто опыта нету, так как реальных проектов на практике не было, все были такие мелочные, эти примеры - для примера, в реальности количество столбцов(rost, ves и т.д.) будет 10-20 больше!

Кто в курсе как лучше подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: кошмар в обоих случаях; насколько помню, на практике достаточно 3 нормальной формы. Для начала определитесь с тем, что вы хотите. Если пользователь захочет изменить имя - вы ему предоставите огромный список с вариантами? Или позволите самому вводить? Скорее всего последнее, а значит имя в отдельную таблицу выносить не надо. Дата в базе - это число (если только у вас это не строка), поэтому дату в отдельную таблицу выносить смысла нет. Переименовывать города же вы не собираетесь? А значит их в той же таблице храните. В комменте не объяснишь всего, можно попробовать в чате, либо ждать ответа

Comment: В какой чат зайти? Или напишите ответ? пожалуйста, а то не могу понять сути...

Comment: я ответы редко пишу, тем более здесь надо много писать. Чат можете либо сами создать, либо [во флудилке](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23460/ru-so#) можно пообщаться (там не только я тогда буду)

Comment: @BOPOH вот создал http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31951/db-optimization